# Raleigh Twenty wheel/rim replacement options

Tags: maintenance, wheels, vintage, wheel-building

What replacement wheels/rims that can be fitted into `Raleigh Twenty` bike are available these days?

Below I focus my requirements on the rims as they are probably easier to come by than complete wheels but if there are new wheels available then I'd love to know the vendor/manufacturer.

Ideally I would like not to modify anything and stick with `20" × 1-3/8"` size with `28 spokes` taking `ISO 35-451` tyres if such option exists at all.

The next acceptable option would be same size with `36 spokes` which would require replacing the hubs (which I hope can be obtained more easily).

Yet another possibility is any other wheel size that would fit the bike without modifications (with the exception of the hubs).

The least acceptable option would be a solution requiring mudguards removal, front fork replacement, brakes change etc. However, out of curiosity I would be happy to see what more drastic routes can be followed.

[image: Here's my beauty! :o)]

Comment: You say "wheel", but then you say you want 28 spokes so you don't have to replace the hubs.  A bike "wheel", as normally spoken, includes the rim, spokes, and hub.  And likely you're best/cheapest option is to replace the entire wheel, if you can find a match, as rebuilding with your old hub would likely cost more, with poorer results.

Comment: I found some 20x1-3/8 wheels on Amazon, but not with a coaster brake rear.  And be aware that fractionally-sized wheels (with "1-3/8" vs "1.375" as a width) are somewhat non-standard anymore, and you must be careful of what you buy.  Consult [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) for the details, to get an exact match.

Comment: I was quite disappointed to see the photo of the bike, after reading *Raleigh Twenty wheel* replacement. It has only *two* wheels!

Comment: And @Daniel, obviously my brain is functioning (or not) differently this morning. I read *A bike "wheel", as normally spoken* as *A bike "wheel", **is** normally spoken*, which seemed a perfectly reasonable way of saying that they usually have spokes :-)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=twenty+inch+bike+wheels

Comment: @Daniel I edited the question to make it clearer what I want. I originally said "wheels" meaning all the parts needed for a wheel rather than a complete wheel and then focused on the rims, as I felt it unlikely to be able to find complete wheels anywhere these days. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @andy256 Thanks Andy. Why not turn this valuable comment into an answer?

Comment: Do note that the rules here do not allow us to give you specific recommendations as to manufacturers or suppliers.

Comment: (And one wonders why these wheels need replacement.  What problems do you have with the existing wheels?)

Comment: Seven years old but relevant: http://www.bikeforums.net/folding-bikes/630528-buying-20-inch-wheel-3-speed-internal-gear-hub.html

Comment: Also relevant (and even older): http://www.bikeforums.net/folding-bikes/318376-do-they-sell-20-rear-wheels-3-speed-internal-hubs-already-installed.html

Comment: (But those two links point out that the Dahon and other folding bikes use 20-inch wheels, and so you might find a suitable replacement from that quarter (though the rim diameter would likely be slightly different).)

Comment: Perhaps I should have used the word 'brand' instead. Is recommending a brand acceptable here, seems a bit strict. In this case nothing wrong with the rims or hubs, but the spokes are in a sorry state and need replacing, some are missing, most lost their shine. When I do do that I could as well upgrade the wheels to something more modern for instance or performs better in wet.

Comment: Sheldon really has all the answers on this http://www.sheldonbrown.com/raleigh-twenty.html . The short answer is that off the shelf wheels don't exist, but the parts to make them do, and it largely depends on what choices you want to make with modifying the frame and fork or not.

Comment: Suggesting searching for 20" wheels isn't very helpful, as 20" doesn't necessarily mean that the wheel is going to be 451mm and the vendors don't always mention it.

Answer (score 5):

The old stainless steel rims can be a pain to stop in, and when it rains, it's pretty much impossible...I'm a member of The Raleigh Twenty forums, gives good info about the bikes. The technical data for the rims is provided below, but there may be other options aside from what's listed.

According to [The Raleigh Twenty Resources](http://raleightwenty.webs.com/technicaldata.htm):

> **Rims:**
>
>   **Alienation Ankle Biter  20 x 1-1/8"** . Lightweight high-performance junior-BMX race rim. Double-walled. Eyeleted. Theoretically available in 28, 32 and 36 hole drillings. I have the 32H version on two bikes. They're very good. Patchy availability.
>   **Sun Ringle ICI-1  20 x 1-1/8"**. Similar to above. 28 and 36 hole drillings. Currently available.
>   **Halo JX-2  20 x 1-1/8"**. Similar to above. 28 and 32 hole drillings. I'm about to build a set. They look very good. Currently available.
>   Crupi Rhythm 20 x 1-1/8". Similar to above but non-eyeleted. Range of anodized colours. 28 hole drilling. Currently available.
>   **Bombshell and RCR carbon-fibre 20 x 1-1/8"**. Currently available but WAY TOO EXPENSIVE!!!  And, may not take high pressures.
>   **Ukai and Araya "old school" BMX race rims  20 x 1-3/8"**. These regularly turn up as "New Old Stock" on eBay. They were made during the BMX boom of the early 1980s, and are normally 36H only. Being single-walled and non-eyeleted, these are basic rims that are no match for the lighter and stronger modern alloy rims listed above. Patchy availabilty.
>   **Ukai "mid school" BMX race rimes 20 x 1-1/8"**. From the 1990s or early 2000s. Occasionally turn up NOS on eBay. These double-walled and eyeleted (sometimes double-eyeleted) Japanese rims are top quality. Rare.
>   **Unbranded Chinese 451 carbon-fibre rims**, direct from the factory online or via eBay. Caveat emptor! Currently available.

Comment: Good stuff and nice forum! Are all the rims here 406mm unless stated otherwise? On the website you are a member of [they say](http://raleightwenty.webs.com/upgradesmodifications.htm) `the rear brake to suit 406mm wheels is a very, very long reach calliper`. Does it imply that replacing of the stock brakes is necessary when switching to 406mm rims? The brake pads on my Twenty are positioned near the top of the slot (as shown on the picture), wouldn't the current brakes (which I believe are originals) have enough reach to work with 406mm rims?